# Javascript : String Array not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass updated testvar to ComponentX

```
let testvar = ["Test", "Test2"];
testvar.map(test => {
test = test + "Edited";
console.log(test);//updates here
return test;
 });
console.log(testvar);//doesn't retrieve updated value
<ComponentX values={testvar}>
```

I am aware that console isn't asynchronous  but I am also passing this updated value to a component,
but original gets passed.
I tried to wrap this update as async function, like below,

```
let testvar = ["Test", "Test2"];
const updateFunc = async()=>{
await testvar.map(test => {
test = test + "Edited";
console.log(test);//updates here
return test;
});
} 
const updatedvalues = updateFunc();   
<ComponentX values={updatedvalues}>
```

I receive errors as promise String[] isnt acceptable on ComponentX.
Any Leads would be helpful.Thanks!

Comment: array.map returns a new array, so you need to say testvar = testvar.map...

Comment: The `map` method doesn't update the array in place, it returns a new array. Assign it to a new variable and log that instead. (Also, don't use `map` for side effects like `console.log` - `forEach` is the method for that.)

Comment: Your `testvar.map` isn't assigned to anything, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: `console` isn't asynchronous and nothing here has anything to do with asynchronicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat to the strings as there are mutable, but actuality there not. In this case you need to update array by index

```
let testvar = ["Test", "Test2"];
testvar.forEach((test,i) => {
testvar[i] = test + "Edited";
console.log(test);//updates here
});
console.log(testvar);
```

or created a new one

```
testvar = testvar.map(test => {
  test = test + "Edited";
  console.log(test);//updates here
  return test;
 });
```